# Cell height of a Dynamic table

Tags: javascript, html, jinja2

I have a dynamic html table (that gets its content from a database file with Jinja for loop).
The first column contains a picture and username of a person.
I want to adjust the font size of the username base on the fixed height of its parent div named 'fitin', so when the name is long it gets smaller instead of going to the second line.

---

### This is my html code:

```
<tdody>
    {% for i in players %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class='fitin'>                             <!-- in css file, .fitin {height: 50px;} -->
                    <div>
                        <img src=''> <p class='username'>{{ i.username }}</p>    <!-- in css file, p {display: inline;} -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>{{ i.join_date }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

---

### and the javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table tr').each(function(){
        console.log($('.fitin').height());        // I get 50 for '.fitin'
        console.log($('.fitin div').height());    // and something like 33 for all the '.fitin div'
    });
});
```

---

For now my problem is that I am unable to get the right height of the div inside the div 'fitin' to reflects the real height, instead I am getting a fixed number for every row even though the displayed table contains few long usernames sitting in the next line to the picture.

Please could you advice me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: If you think the actual problem is with the height of div, then you can restrict the height by using max-height: 50px;

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted isn't HTML, it's your templating code. If you post the actual HTML output of a broken instance as a JSFiddle, that'd be ideal.

After reading your comment, I understand your problem now. You're always getting the *first* `.fitin` div. This code will work:

```
$('table tr').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).find('.fitin').height());        // I get 50 for '.fitin'
    console.log($(this).find('.fitin div').height());    // and something like 33 for all the '.fitin div'
});
```

Now you will be referring to *each* `<tr>`'s child `.fitin`.

Comment: I apologize @gladsocc, I don't understand you clearly, I thought templating code is same as HTML code? 1) you said the height isn't changing, but when I use Inspect Element on Chrome, it reads different height with the long username! 2) I just used the width now but I'm still getting the same value for all the row, and it's not even the correct width of the first p comparing to Inspect Element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and letm know...

```
var cHeight1 = document.getElementsByClassName('.fitin').clientHeight;
var cHeight2 = document.getElementsByClassName('.fitin div').clientHeight;
```

or

```
var oHeight1 = document.getElementById('.fitin').offsetHeight;
var oHeight2 = document.getElementById('.fitin div').offsetHeight;
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Inspired by your suggetion @Ajay Makwana, I tried to use getElementsByClassName to make sure that I'm getting different values of each person, like this: var cHeight1 = document.getElementsByClassName('username'); console.log(cHeight1[0].innerHTML); but I got the first username for all the tables row, like (Mike * 130 times, since the table has 130 entry at that time). It's like the function only execute with first row and not the rest.. Did you understand my problem?